# datetime error TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Tags: pandas, datetime

Hi I am trying to drop a row from a Data frame, loaded from a CSV file that looks like[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/td6q0.png):

```
no_show_appointment['ScheduledDay'] = pd.datetime(no_show_appointment.ScheduledDay)
```

but i get this error: `TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>`

Comment: pd.datetime(no_show_appointment.ScheduledDay,errors ='coerce')

Comment: I tried this but the result seems to be the same.

Comment: Best provide your data as runnable code, not as screenshot. Then we can reproduce the error and help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20159305/463796 on how to write good pandas questions.